# I'm looking at a problem with php displaying something

Tags: php

I have just done a php contact form for my website, but what I get is this:

https://gyazo.com/2f3c4faa5bc253a6e3ff94d78214867d

And the code I'm using is this:

```
<?php
include('***Contains private stuff***.php');
//Send mail function
function send_mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers){
    return @mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}

if($_POST) {

    $to = "***PRIVATE MAIL***"; // Your email here
    $subject = 'Message from my website'; // Subject message here

        //MySQL
        $query = "INSERT INTO contact (name, email, subject, message) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$subject', '$message')";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        //Sanitize input data, remove all illegal characters
        $name    = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $email    = filter_var($_POST['mail'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $subject = filter_var($_POST['subject'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $message = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        //Send Mail
        $headers = 'From: ' . $email .''. "\r\n".
            'Reply-To: '.$email.'' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


        $sent = send_mail($to, $subject, $message . "\r\n\n"  .'Name: '.$name. "\r\n" .'Email: '.$email, $headers);
        if (! $sent) {
            // log the error
            error_log('Mail Error: Message to ' . $to . ' wasn\'t sent');
        }
}
?>
```

And I just want to remove it, but can't really figure out the issue.
Link to my friends website I'm using for the testing, and live view.

http://thomasmaneschijn.com/lukas/

And you should be able to see my html code on the site as well.
Reason I marked the include section out is because there is some passwords and stuff that I don't want to leak.

Comment: you dont want to see the error even if an error occurred?

Comment: Well, I mean it destroys my websites layout completely, which is annoying.

Comment: now your site is not working 500 error

Comment: Fixed, should be showing site now.

Comment: Well if you don’t want JSON-encoded data structures to show up in your page … then don’t output JSON-encoded data structures in the first place … Returning such data would make sense if you were making a background request to this script. But if you just want to submit your form to this normally, and this is supposed to provide the response in the form of the “next page” … well, then output error messages in a user-friendly way somewhere in the actual content, instead of spitting out JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have few issues in your code:

***Issue 1,*** Your code is wide open for SQL Injection, you must need to prevent your code with SQL Injection.

***Issue 2,*** You are calling `send_mail()` without using any check, you need to move this inside the `if($_POST)` check, otherwise, it will execute on every page refresh.

***Issue 3,*** Your INSERT query placement is wrong, from where you define these variables `VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$subject', '$message')` before this query?

According to your screen shot, you are getting json response just because of `send_mail()` method, if you move your code something like:

```
// Move `send_mail()` method here
if($_POST) {
// Your Variables
// Your Query / MYSQL / suggest you to use PDO here.
// Your method calling
}
```

**Some helpful links:**

*[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*

*[Are PDO prepared statements sufficient to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection)*

Always use [`error_reporting()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) on local environment.

Comment: I will for sure, do that.

Comment: @luk19987 try them

Comment: @luk19987: emails are working before???, please update your question with updated code

Comment: I edited it. Changed it to the code I use now, but not getting mails.

Comment: @luk19987: emails was working before? check error by using `error_get_last()`

Comment: Where do I put that? And I used a other system before, but was working, but I had some other issues with that.

Comment: @luk19987: where you are using error_log on failure. `var_dump(error_get_last())`

Comment: I'm using error_log when it doesn't get a mail, I checked the log after I sent two mails and nothing appeared even in my mail.

Comment: array(4) `{ ["type"]=> int(8) ["message"]=> string(21) "Undefined index: mail" ["file"]=> string(43) "/home2/thomasma/public_html/lukas/index.php" ["line"]=> int(19) }` this is what i get from the website.

Comment: @luk19987 then u must need to check your line no 19

Comment: check `print_r($_POST)` or check this field `$_POST['mail']` @luk19987

Comment: `array(4) { ["type"]=> int(8) ["message"]=> string(27) "Undefined variable: message" ["file"]=> string(43) "/home2/thomasma/public_html/lukas/index.php" ["line"]=> int(14) }` Fixed that other error, was a typo. But now this.

Comment: @luk19987: as i mention issue no 3

Comment: Aight fixed it, I had misplaced my MySQL and it could send the data to my database.

Comment: I will check if I get any mails now.

Comment: Still no luck with the mail being sent. But I think everything else if working fine.

Comment: @luk19987: yes so i think u need to use smtp here.

Comment: How do I add that? I have read about it, but I looked a bit confusing at start. I know it sounds a little n**bish to ask that. Just every new to php.

Comment: there are so many example available on SO @luk19987: but i think, first of all you need to debug more.. like use one liner code to test email like `mail('your email','subject','test');` place this right at the top of the file, if its work, then no need to use smtp, otherwise, you need to move on to smtp. or contact to hosting provider.

Comment: @luk19987: now u can close this question becuasse this question is related to `php displaying something` for email , u can create an another question.

Comment: Aight, I will do that.

Answer (score 2):

Your `$to` is not a valid email.

EDIT

To better understand your error, at least while developing I'd do the following:

```
if(@mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
    echo json_encode(array('info' => 'success', 'msg' => "Your message has been sent. Thank you!"));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Error, your message hasn't been sent", 'error_info' => error_get_last()['message']));
}
```

See if that works.

You can also use this to better understand your error -

```
$sendMail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
if(!$sendMail) { $errorMessage = error_get_last()['message']; }
```

Comment: i dont think so, maybe OP dont want to show email address

Comment: I know, reason being is it's my private mail I use for testing purposes. I don't want to leak it.

Comment: You can use `$sendMail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)` and
`if (!$sendMail) { $errorMessage = error_get_last()['message']; }` to better understand your error.

Answer (score 2):

`@mail()` returns `TRUE` if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, `FALSE` otherwise. [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

So I guess that you have some problems with the params passed to the function.
Consider the first `if`, if there is no `$_POST` you are actually not going to have those two variables defined.
Also, since the `send_mail()` function is just called at the end of the file, it is going to be triggered upon visiting the page.

So my guess on this is that when you visit the page without having anything in the `$_POST` variable, you are going to miss the needed parameters for the `send_email`. Maybe try to dump the values of the parameters once you are inside `send_email()`

Comment: Maybe you're correct, I can try and comment out the send_mail function? Just to see what happens?

Comment: If you comment the line where `send_email()` is called the message won't appear because the function is not going to be triggered :)
I think that you control for `$_POST` because you are going to get those params for there later, but as long as you are testing just define the variables outside that if or make some sort of button/something like that to send the email

Comment: i agreed with you my vote for u. but OP having few more issues in code, check my answer.

Comment: Checked, I think you got this one ;) gj

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
include('***Contains private stuff***.php');
if($_POST) {

    $to = "***PRIVATE MAIL***"; // Your email here
    $subject = 'Message from my website'; // Subject message here

}

//Send mail function
function send_mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers){
    return @mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}

//MySQL
$query = "INSERT INTO contact (name, email, subject, message) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$subject', '$message')";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

//Sanitize input data, remove all illegal characters
$name    = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email    = filter_var($_POST['mail'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$subject = filter_var($_POST['subject'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$message = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//Send Mail
$headers = 'From: ' . $email .''. "\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


$sent = send_mail($to, $subject, $message . "\r\n\n"  .'Name: '.$name. "\r\n" .'Email: '.$email, $headers);
if (! $sent) {
    // log the error
    error_log('Mail Error: Message to ' . $to . ' wasn\'t sent');
}
?>
```

[PHP error_log](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php)